# Pjsip crashed on android when calling it's functions in multi-threads

Tags: android, multithreading, crash, pjsip

I followed the pjsip 'get started' document and built the pjsip libs for android 9 successfully. But when I use it in my android project (though JNI calls), it usually crash when I register user to sip sever or make calls out.I create pjsua modules in the main thread with APIs such as pjsua_create and pjsua_init, then I call pjsua_acc_add or pjsua_call_make_call in another thread, it usually crash.However, the point it crashed on is quite random.Besides, some times it doesn't crash, but it failed on pjsip_resolve function.It make sip message destination IP and port information, something like '192.168.0.1:5060', to a string without IP information, something like ':5060'.And I have made pj thread check yet, so it doesn't crash for that.Anybody met this problem yet? I had searched out through google and trac.pjsip.org, but can't get any useful information.

Any help will be very appreciated!

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/aries/aries:4.1.1/JRO03L/JLB22.0:user/release-keys'
pid: 3927, tid: 4082, name: Thread-1052  >>> com.ailiao.vp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000017
Stack frame #00  pc 0013c124  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so: Routine ioqueue_on_accept_complete in ../src/pj/activesock.c:916
Stack frame #01  pc 0013c3e4  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so (pj_hash_get_lower+76): Routine pj_array_erase in ../src/pj/array.c:46
Crash dump is completed

********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/aries/aries:4.1.1/JRO03L/JLB22.0:user/release-keys'
pid: 4387, tid: 4415, name: Thread-1051  >>> com.ailiao.vp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000f09 
Stack frame #00  pc 0013c124/data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so: Routine ioqueue_on_accept_complete in ../src/pj/activesock.c:916
Stack frame #01  pc 0013c3e4  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so (pj_hash_get_lower+76): Routine pj_array_erase in ../src/pj/array.c:46
Crash dump is completed

********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/aries/aries:4.1.1/JRO03L/JLB22.0:user/release-keys'
pid: 4532, tid: 4613, name: Thread-1060  >>> com.ailiao.vp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000038
Stack frame #00  pc 0013c124  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so: Routine ioqueue_on_accept_complete in ../src/pj/activesock.c:916
Stack frame #01  pc 0013c468  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so: Routine pj_array_find in ../src/pj/array.c:60
Crash dump is completed

********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/aries/aries:4.1.1/JRO03L/JLB22.0:user/release-keys'
pid: 6317, tid: 6572, name: Thread-1115  >>> com.ailiao.vp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr e92d4808
Stack frame #00  pc 0013f484  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so: Routine pj_list_insert_nodes_before in ../include/pj/list_i.h:54
Stack frame #01  pc 0013f744  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so (pj_hash_get_lower+76): Routine pj_list_init in ../include/pj/list.h:90
Stack frame #02  pc 0008e80c  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so (pjsip_ua_register_dlg+360): Routine pjsip_ua_destroy in ../src/pjsip/sip_ua_layer.c:230
Stack frame #03  pc 0008934c  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so (pjsip_dlg_create_uac+1880): Routine pjsip_dlg_create_uac in ../src/pjsip/sip_dialog.c:240
Stack frame #04  pc 00032f50  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so (pjsua_call_make_call+1152): Routine on_make_call_med_tp_complete in ../src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_call.c:459
Stack frame #05  pc 00026038  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so (Java_sua_Pjsua_makeCall+728): Routine Java_sua_Pjsua_InnerInit in jni/../src/pjsuawrapper.cc:767
Stack frame #06  pc 0001fb70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
Stack frame #07  pc 0004e8b9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+360)
Stack frame #08  pc 00050603  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmResolveNativeMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+174)
Stack frame #09  pc 00029020  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #10  pc 0002d7e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
Stack frame #11  pc 0005fed5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
Stack frame #12  pc 0005feff  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
Stack frame #13  pc 00055327  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #14  pc 00012e70  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
Stack frame #15  pc 000125c8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
Stack frame #16  pc ffffffff  <unknown>: Unable to open symbol file obj\local\armeabi-v7a/<unknown>. Error (123): Unknown error
Crash dump is completed

********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/aries/aries:4.1.1/JRO03L/JLB22.0:user/release-keys'
pid: 7766, tid: 8023, name: Thread-1123  >>> com.ailiao.vp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 20e7a813
Stack frame #00  pc 00014682  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+1589)
Stack frame #01  pc 00016fef  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+10)
Stack frame #02  pc 0014a728  /data/data/com.ailiao.vp/lib/libsua.so: Routine default_block_alloc in ../src/pj/pool_policy_malloc.c:46
```

Answer (score 2):

Build with `NDK_DEBUG=1` and you will get a more verbose stack trace. For me, the crash is coming from:

```
: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I: Build fingerprint: 'asus/WW_Z00T/ASUS_Z00T:5.0.2/LRX22G/WW_user_1.17.40.1234_20160304:user/release-keys'
I: Revision: '0'
I: ABI: 'arm64'
I: pid: 5618, tid: 5924, name: OutgoingCall-si  >>> com.siptest.android <<<
I: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I: Abort message: '../src/pjsip/sip_ua_layer.c:290: pjsip_ua_register_dlg: assertion "dlg->local.info && dlg->local.info->tag.slen && dlg->local.tag_hval != 0" failed'
I:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000001724  x2   0000000000000006  x3   000000558de365b0
I:     x4   000000558de365b0  x5   0000000000000005  x6   0000000000000001  x7   0000000000000020
I:     x8   0000000000000083  x9   fefefefeff63646b  x10  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f  x11  0000000000000001
I:     x12  0000000000000001  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  002dee82e7a00ada
I:     x16  0000007f7d43e483  x17  0000000000000001  x18  0000000000000000  x19  000000558de365b0
I:     x20  0000007f7d43fbb0  x21  0000007fa017a000  x22  0000000000000058  x23  0000000000000006
I:     x24  00000000130e4360  x25  00000000130785a0  x26  000000558dd88930  x27  00000000130e4a20
I:     x28  00000000130785a0  x29  0000007f7d43e720  x30  0000007fa00f48bc
I:     sp   0000007f7d43e720  pc   0000007fa0139de8  pstate 0000000060000000
I:     #00 pc 000000000005ede8  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
I:     #01 pc 00000000000198b8  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+160)
I:     #02 pc 000000000001ae18  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
I:     #03 pc 000000000001467c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
I:     #04 pc 0000000000016ca8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_fatal+128)
I:     #05 pc 0000000000014754  /system/lib64/libc.so (__assert2+40)
I:     #06 pc 00000000001d5ddc  /data/app/com.siptest.android-2/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_ua_register_dlg+248)
I:     #07 pc 00000000001d1588  /data/app/com.siptest.android-2/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_dlg_create_uac+1688)
I:     #08 pc 00000000001634a8  /data/app/com.siptest.android-2/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pjsua_call_make_call+1088)
I:     #09 pc 0000000000145ce0  /data/app/com.siptest.android-2/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pj::Call::makeCall(std::string const&, pj::CallOpParam const&)+168)
I:     #10 pc 00000000000fd1f8  /data/app/com.siptest.android-2/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (Java_org_pjsip_pjsua2_pjsua2JNI_Call_1makeCall+256)
I:     #11 pc 000000000075b9d4  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.siptest.android-2@base.apk@classes.dex
W: RecordThread: buffer overflow
```

Which seems to indicate a problem with the registration credentials. I dug into the C source, and discovered one of the following fields is `NULL` sip_dialog.c:

```
/*
 * Create an UAC dialog.
 */
PJ_DEF(pj_status_t) pjsip_dlg_create_uac( pjsip_user_agent *ua,
                      const pj_str_t *local_uri,
                      const pj_str_t *local_contact,
                      const pj_str_t *remote_uri,
                      const pj_str_t *target,
                      pjsip_dialog **p_dlg)
{
    pj_status_t status;
    pj_str_t tmp;
    pjsip_dialog *dlg;

    /* Check arguments. */
    PJ_ASSERT_RETURN(ua && local_uri && remote_uri && p_dlg, PJ_EINVAL);
```

I've also read other users complain that multi-threading on Android has issues. Be sure you attach the JVM before making pjsip library calls. Maybe try:

```
  ua_cfg.setThreadCnt(1);
  ua_cfg.setMainThreadOnly(true);
```

And then you will have to pass that thread any action. Alternatively, you can enable multiple threads and then attach like this:

```
  static boolean attachJVM()
  {
    // ensure after possibly sleeping on take()
    final Endpoint ep = endpoint();
    try { if (!ep.libIsThreadRegistered()) ep.libRegisterThread(Thread.currentThread().getName()); return true; }
    catch (Exception e) { log().e(e); return false; }
  }
```

I realize I'm making calls to my own utilities there, but I think it's pretty self-descriptive (i.e. log() is a log file and endpoint() returns the instance of Endpoing you built at init).

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with this library for a long time - it crashes.

After some investigations on nicely caught error log I have found a common reason for most of the library crashes.
See my answer and comments here (not sure if copy-paste is allowed here):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46111654/6248423

Comment: You can copy from it and tailor it to this question if it is your answer.